# How to randomize by hash (in Java)?

Tags: java, hash, random

I have ArrayList of Strings. I need to randomize it by "hash number".
Example:

ArrayList: "Word", "Simple", "Another", "Demo"
hash: 1234567

As a result of randomizing I want to receive say: "Simple", "Word", "Demo", "Another"

with other hash: 542345 I want to receive say: "Word", "Another", "Demo", "Simple"

But the requirements is that that when I *always* sort by this hash the randomizing order will always be THE SAME for that HASH.

Any suggestions? Adviscs?

Comment: why is consistent hashing marked as a tag? It's a diff algo for DHT routing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [shuffle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29) a List using a Random object that you initialize with the hash.

```
Collections.shuffle( myList, new Random(12345) );
```

When the same hash is used to seed the Random object, the shuffle order should turn out the same.

Comment: Thanks; I couldn't find any doc confirming that shuffle by same Random object will return the same collection. Can you please point me to one? Thanks!

Comment: @alexeypro: It can be inferred from the docs of the two methods involved [Collections.shuffle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29) and the [Random(long)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28long%29) constructor.  Passing the same seed to the Random constructor will insure that the RNG is in the same initial state each time shuffle is called, resulting in the same ordering of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "hash" (whatever than means) as a seed to the random number generator?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
value1 = "hello" --> value1.hashCode() = 99162322  
value2 = "hello" --> value2.hashCode() = 99162322
```

So, if you 'really' need to use a Hash, then you can iterate through the ArrayList, sum up all the hash values generated and save it.

Now, when you need to verify that the hash is same or not, again iterate through the new arraylist, generate the hashcode(), sum it up and check.

But it's an overkill. You can simply use shuffle() as suggested by Bill.